# Nginx Subdomains: Redirect /.well-known path for Let's Encrypt

Tags: redirect, meteor, nginx, subdomain, lets-encrypt

I have an Nginx Server running with two sub-domains. One of them uses a proxy_pass to redirect everything to a Meteor Application and the other sub-domain just uses Laravel but in a diffrent directory than the normal domain.

So, when I start `./letsencrypt-auto` I get the following error-message for both sub-domains:

```
Failed authorization procedure. subdomain.mydomain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized ::
The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://subdomain.mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xyzxyzxy_xzyzxyxyyx_xyzyxzyxz: "<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
```

My interpretation of that is, that it doesn't work because my Laravel-Subdomain is not in `/var/www/domain.com/html` but in `/var/www/laravel/html` and my Meteor-Application is somwhere else and ngnix just does the proxy passing.

**So my question is:** Can I redirect `/.well-known/acme-challenge` for both subdomains to the real /.well-known so that letsencrypt-auto doesn't throw this error?

---

### More Information:

I've tried

```
location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
    default_type "text/plain";
    root /tmp/letsencrypt-auto;
}
```

but it didn't work...

Config for my Meteor sub-domain:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        # SSL configuration
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

        […] SSL stuff […]


        server_name meteor.domain.com;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

}
```

Config for my Laravel sub-domain:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name laravel.domain.com;

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

        […] SSL stuff […]

        root /var/www/laravel/html;


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

    location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, thanks to the tips from Richard Smith I solved it:

I kept this in the Config-Part for the domain.com-Part as described in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

but put that into the Config-Part for subdomain.domain.com instead:

```
location /.well-known/ {
    root /var/www/domain.com/html;
}
```

What it does is handling any request to `subdomain.domain.com/.well-known/[anything]` as `domain.com/.well-known/[anything]`, thus no error from letsencrypt-auto.

Answer (score 2):

Your `location ~ /.well-known` blocks are regex locations and will take precedence over the prefix location you are attempting to add.

You need to delete them.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) on the `location` directive.